# Constant length code snippets

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, internet-explorer

I have noticed that when we use code markups, the code gets re-formatted and syntax-highlighted; but if a block of code of say, 100 lines, is posted, all the lines are visible.

Instead, what about using the vertical scrollbar and limiting the code snippet size to a fixed maximum length, say 20 lines, allowing the user to see the rest of the code using the scrollbar?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36979/where-to-paste-large-blocks-of-code-text

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens already. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005192/how-to-speed-up-the-code) for an example of a question with a large block of code posted.

Answer (score 1):

Mike's correct, this is already the default behavior, are you using some custom script or stylesheet that's overriding the `overflow: auto;` on the `<pre>` element, or possibly using a browser that doesn't support `max-height`?

The relevant styling (as of the time of this post) is this:

```
pre {
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height and specifically [Jeff's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707/ie8-overflowauto-with-max-height/881597#881597).

Comment: @ccomet: Ah IE, the special kid...I'd call this a non-issue, an inferior browser will yield an inferior experience, same goes for buying a car (though it's a free choice here, and by inferior I mean in terms of supporting these CSS properties).  I wouldn't say this is broken, it *works*, it just isn't the optimal experience.

Comment: It isn't always a free choice.

Comment: @mmyers - I meant cost-wise :) I understand it may be a *limited* choice, I have several friends in that situation where they work.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am using IE7. Let me try the same with some other browsers.